# Linker can't find shared object with Libunbound

Tags: c, linker, unbound

I'm trying to run some code using the <unbound.h> library.
I'm using an example from the [Unbound docs.](https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/libunbound-tutorial-1/)

I compiled and installed Unbound, following [these steps.](https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/howto-setup/)

Now, I can compile the example using

```
gcc -o example eample_1.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lunbound
```

When running ./example

I get the following error:

```
./example: error while loading shared libraries: libunbound.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, when I go to /usr/local/lib, I can see libunbound.so.8 and other .so files.

Why can't the linker find this file on run-time?

EDIT:

I fixed it by running /sbin/ldconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Your compile/link statement is asking for a file that does not exist.
It is asking for `libunbound,so` but the actual name is: `libunbound,so,8`

To correct the problem, in the same directory as the desired file, place a link from the desired name to the actual name of the file,